# How do I import a view?

Tags: views, 8

Recently, I migrated Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 using the [Migrate upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module, but the views aren't migrated.

Is there any method to import views from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no upgrade path for views from D6/D7 to D8 and plans for this in core are postponed.

See the latest comment for this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2500547#comment-11402389. There is a contrib project mentioned, but this is at very early stage.

Comment: The issue was closed as Won't Fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project named [Views Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tools) that maybe will help you, I didn't test it, but here is the description of it (from its project page):

> Views Tools is very useful and comes handy with the following
> features:
>
> **Drupal 7 Release Features:**
>
> 1: View display(s) can be exported (same like you export a view).
>
> 2: View display(s) can be saved as new View.
>
> 3: Displays can be deleted without loading the whole view.
>
> To use this goto Structure >> Views Tools.
>
> **Drupal 8 Release Features:**
>
> 1: Backup of a View(export a single view to YAML).
>
> 2: View display(s) can be exported to a new view.
>
> 3: View display(s) can be saved as new View.
>
> 4: Displays can be deleted without loading the whole view.
>
> To use this goto Structure >> Views Tools.